# componentDidUpdate prevProps shows new values when using es6 and Babel

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, reactjs-flux

See the TodoMVC app [here](http://singhshashi.github.io/react-es6-bug). Code for the same is [here](https://github.com/singhshashi/react-flux-kefir-es6-todomvc-example)

When you add a todo and edit it, the first value logged in the console should be the value before edit, and the second value, value after edit.

However, both the values logged are values after edit. The prevProps does not get passed. This issue is not seen in the original TodoMVC-flux written in js/jsx by Bill Fisher.

I think this is a bug with Babel but I haven't been able to pinpoint.

Comment: Any chance you're looking at logs in Chrome where the console shows 'present state' of logged objects (thus making before and after logs look the same)? This has thrown me off with similar symptoms in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this was happening was due to mutating the state object and gets resolved when you take the immutable approach.

In the TodoMVC-flux written by Bill Fisher he is returning a new object.

For more details see https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/componentdidupdate-prevprops-has-new-values-instead-of-old-when-using-es6-and-babel/3695